# Can an SD card be damaged because of different transfer speeds between a device and the card

Tags: sd-card

I have a Nintendo Switch that accepts SD cards that transfer at speeds 60 - 95 MB/s

[https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22481/~/microsd-card-faq#s1q3](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22481/%7E/microsd-card-faq#s1q3)

I bought and SD card that is UHS-1 compatible, but is slower in transfer speeds than what the console asks.

Can that SD card be damaged because of different transfer speeds between a device and the card ?
Do I need to format it before using that on a cell phone (or other device) ?

I have looked for this information, but this is the closest to what I need.

https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/sd-card-read-write-speed-error-recovery/

This is also a similar question but not the same that I'm asking
[Can a device ruin an SD Card or microSD card?](https://superuser.com/questions/1325625/can-a-device-ruin-an-sd-card-or-microsd-card)

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to use *any* SD or XD (or µXD in an adapter) flash memory card in a device that accepts that SD or XD card, whether slower or faster than the speed of the device. The only issue is that transfer would be at the slowest of the two speeds.

However, often a device will *format* the card *specifically for that device*. For example, a camera may add a folder, [DCIM](https://www.techhive.com/article/217111/dcim_folder.html), but a book ereader might have a different file structure. It is usually safe to put any XD/SD card into a computer to *read* the data, but transferring a card from phone to camera or to ereader may cause corruption of the file system.

One caution: each time a card is inserted or removed from a device, there is danger of damage due to electrostatic discharge (ESD). Cards and ports have *some* ESD protection, but a big spark between the card in your hand and the device can cause damage. Best practice is to touch and hold a metal part of the device before inserting a card to "short circuit" static before it kills the card or port.